# Windows server 2003 R2 problem with resetting user password

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-management

I am trying to help a friend and with the limited knowledge I have about the server setup ,here are the 2 problems

1. Resetting a user password does not work
2. New user created cannot logon to the domain

The server is a domain controller

Some pointers please?

Many thanks

Comment: Is this only happening on a single computer, or can the new users created or the one that had the password reset login to other domain connected computers?

Comment: "does not work" isn't too helpful. So what happens when he attempts to do these things? What error messages do they get, including from the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts would be that the computer you are trying to access the network with has lost its relationship to the server - rejoin it to the domain (log on as local admin)

How many users?
How many computers?
All users effected?
Any services not working?
Server does have valid network connectivity to the rest of the machines?
What's changed recently?

These questions will help us resolve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS settings of the computer in question with local admin and see if it is using the server or another source.  If you type in a random username or password on the computer does it tell you that the domain can't be found?  It most likely a name resolving issue or it's lost the relationship.